# UITableViewCellのdetailTextLabel値が複数行にわたる際に、UITableViewCellの高さの動的変更について

Tags: swift, xcode

UITableViewCell について質問があります。
UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle を使用して、detailTextLabel を表現する際、
複数行に渡る文字列について、行の高さを動的に変更することができません。

Storyboad で cell に UILabel を配置して AutoLayout をすることで動的に高さを変更するケースはよく見られるのですが、下記のとおり detailTextLabel を使用して、高さを動的に変更する表現はできるのでしょうか。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    // セルを再利用する。
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "テスト"
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "あいうえおかきくけこさしすせそなにぬねのはひふへほあいうえおかきくけこさしすせそなにぬねのはひふへほ"

    return cell!
}
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Quite - UITableViewCellの高さを動的に変更する（初心者向け）](http://qiita.com/kotaroito/items/8bd2f10833e07f7a5809)

こちらの記事を参考にして、こういうプログラムを作ってみました。
考え方は、NSString Class (UIKit Additions) の`boundingRectWithSize()`メソッドを使って、テキストを表示するのに必要な矩型サイズを求め、それから行の高さを計算するというものです。`detailTextLabel`の高さを求め、それに`textLabel`の高さと、マージンを加えて、行の高さとしています。

*UITableViewDelegate*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let text: NSString = myDetailText as NSString // myDetailTextは、detailTextLabelに入力するテキスト。NSStringにキャストする。
    let labelWidth = tableView.bounds.size.width - 30.0 // 30.0は適当。正しくdetailTextLabelの幅を計算してください。
    let maxSize = CGSize(width: labelWidth, height: CGFloat.max)
    let attribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11.0)] // デフォルトのdetailTextLabelのフォントとそのサイズ。これも適切な値にしてください。
    let size = text.boundingRectWithSize(maxSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attribute, context: nil).size

    return size.height + 28.0 // この28.0も適当な数字。
}
```

*正直言わせてもらうと、`UITableViewCell`のサブクラスを作って、`UILabel`を`addSubview()`して、Constraintをかけて、ってやる方が、楽だと思いました。*

Comment: いつもご丁寧にありがとうございます。
計算して高さを割り出す必要があるのですね。
UITableViewCell のサブクラスを作成する方向も検討したいと思います。
ありがとうございました。